# how to prevent content from appearing at all - responsive web design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is it possible to prevent certain data from appearing depending on the size of the device? 
For example, I'm in the process of removing a table - I'm changing it to a grid made up of `<div>` tags.

If the user is on a desktop, I'd like to be able to show something like this:

```
<div class="row show-grid" id="tblheading" naming="tblheading">
        <div class="span1">Branch</div>
        <div class="span1">Branch Name</div>
        <div class="span1">Building</div>
        <div class="span1">Building Name</div>
        <div class="span1">Room</div>
        <div class="span1">Asset Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row show-grid">
        <div class="span1">CAN</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span1">CAN-Building1</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span1">CAN-Building1-Room1</div>
        <div class="span1">Value 123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row show-grid">
        <div class="span1">CAN</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span1">CAN-Building2</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span1">CAN-Building2-Room1</div>
        <div class="span1">Value xyz</div>
    </div>
```

But if they're on a mobile device, I don't want to display the first "row" with the headers.  If possible, I'd also like to remove some of the other fields and only show the asset name for mobile devices. 
I'm just new to responsive design so I apologize for any remedial questions.  If you can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: The data you're displaying above looks very much like tabular data - which is what tables are meant to be used to display. Is there a real benefit to converting this table to divs in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) in the Bootstrap docs, it talks about the built-in classes for this.

[image]

You could use these classes to show and hide columns or rows based on screen size. If the differences are significant enough, you could create multiple tables and show the appropriate one for each size.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a case of adding a class to the rows/ cells you'd want to hide and then having that class set to display: none in the media queries targeting mobile devices.
I think the twitter bootstrap even has such classes already built in, but can't remember the exact names.